# Json API Curl to HTTParty request. The request works on my local machine with cURL, but not in Heroku production with HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl, heroku, httparty

So, I've gotten to the point that I'm not sure what question to ask anymore when researching my issue. So by coming here, I'm asking 2 things.

First, how do I got about investigating issues like this in the future?
Second, what am I doing wrong right now?

Basically, I created an app and pushed it to Heroku. This app has API endpoints that work exactly as I expect them to when I am running the app locally and sending curl commands through my terminal. The code I'm running to try to sign-in to my app uses the HTTP gem and is returning `{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}`.

So, this is my first time trying to connect to any API endpoint, so I'm flying a bit in the dark here. What I read about a 500 error is, "When all else fails; generally, a 500 response is used when processing fails due to unanticipated circumstances on the server side, which causes the server to error out." Which sounds a bit like a catch-all for somethings broken but we don't know what, other than it's on the backend. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

What do I do next?

This is the curl command I'm running to send an email and password to receive and auth_token:

```
curl -d "user_login[email]=fake@email.com&user_login[password]=password123" http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sign-in
```

As expected I get this back:

```
{"auth_token":"628f3ebc47193665e7f1d32ae41ff9a7"}%
```

This is the code I'm running using HTTParty to try and connect with my API in production using Heroku:

consume_api.rb

```
require "rubygems"
require "httparty"

query_hash = { :user_login => "fake@email.com",
               :password => "password123" }

response = HTTParty.post("https://fake-heroku-94488.herokuapp.com/api/v1/sign-in", :query => query_hash)

puts response.body, response.code, response.message, response.headers.inspect
```

This is the response back:

```
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
500
Internal Server Error
{"server"=>["Cowboy"], "date"=>["Fri, 03 Feb 2017 14:49:40 GMT"], "connection"=>["close"], "content-type"=>["application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8"], "x-request-id"=>["5d094cee-11a2-4040-abfd-5180f5e46886"], "x-runtime"=>["0.003503"], "vary"=>["Origin"], "content-length"=>["46"], "via"=>["1.1 vegur"]}
```

To reiterate my questions are what can I take from this response to start investigating further? What questions should I be asking myself when this happens?

Second, What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit:

A quick update is that I ran the curl command that worked locally with the actual URL for my production site and it worked exactly as it does locally. I still can't manage to get further using HTTParty.

I checked out my `heroku logs` and found this:

```
2017-02-03T17:22:26.576272+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/v1/sign-in" host=fake-heroku-94488.herokuapp.com request_id=9ab76ce0-95f3-4479-8672-874a624c070e fwd="108.11.195.58" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=265
Started POST "/api/v1/sign-in" for 108.11.195.58 at 2017-02-03 17:22:26 +0000
Processing by Api::V1::SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"email"=>"fake@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/api/v1/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

Which points to line 7 of my SessionsController:

```
    ...
6          def create
7           resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(:email => params[:user_login][:email])
8            return invalid_login_attempt unless resource
    ...
```

Line 7 has two arrays in it, but I'm not sure how they're empty in the Httpary request and just find in the curl request.

Comment: `params[:user_login][:email]` -> `params[:email]` because `{"email"=>"fake@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}` has no `:user_login`

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I took me a while to figure out how to appropriately supply the :user_login.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my first question of what I should do if I bump into this issue or one like it again is to **check out the Heroku logs**. That started the unwinding of my problems. The second part of this answer is that even when I figured out that I wasn't sending in the `:user_login` info, I still couldn't figure out how to fix my issue, so I started dropping `byebug` into anyplace related to my issue and asking what my variables values were and running code to see the output in console. When they kept coming back `nil` and I couldn't figure out what the right order/way to right the HTTParty request, I started putting **`.methods`** or **`.instance_methods`** after my variables to find more ways to ask what is going on here. After that I spent time in rails console, using whatever instance_methods that were associated with my variables until I put the pieces together.

The answer to my second question, what was I doing wrong? I wasn't sending in `:user_login`, mainly because I didn't quite understand what it was supposed to be doing (I'm new, I use a lot of tutorials that I understand like 95% of, this was from the 5%) and even when I did, I couldn't figure out how to shove it in my request. As it turns out, I also wasn't using `:body` appropriatly. Once I figure out that I need to put `:body` around all of the data that I was sending in, my next layer was `:user_login` then followed by my `:email` and `:password`, which with hindsight looks perfectly obvious now.

This is what the code to sign in to my app looks like:

consume_api.rb

```
require "rubygems"
require "httparty"

response = HTTParty.post("https://fake-heroku-94488.herokuapp.com/api/v1/sign-in", :body => {:user_login => {:email => "fake@email.com", :password => "password123"}})


puts response.body, response.code, response.message, response.headers.inspect
```